# module does not see my values inside the main code

Tags: python, module, global-variables

I'm very new to Python and currently am building a GUI interface in Tkinter and have a fully working code for it. I thought it would be nice to have a button work from keyboard by pressing "Enter" key.

The code line for that is:`win.bind('<Return>', testButton.functionName)`
Then you just put "event" in function bracket aka `functionName(event)` And everything works great.

The issue is that now it does not work when you press the button inside the GUI interface what means I need to duplicate and reName one of the functions to have both.

Since it is an identical code, it would make more sense to have it as a module. However, when I import my module it does not seem to see the rest of my code and claims that my variables do not exist.

Here is a simplified example of how I'm doing it.

My module saved as moduleTest:

```
def test():
    sum = a + b
    return sum
```

Main program:

```
import moduleTest

a = 10
b = 12
moduleTest.test()

print test()
```

It keeps claiming that a and b are not defined.

I'm clearly misunderstanding how modules work cause in my mind when I import a module it should simply import the whole code and do the same thing as this:

```
import moduleTest

a = 10
b = 12
def test():
    sum = a + b
    return sum

print test()
```

What am I misunderstanding and doing wrong?

Comment: Python globals are global to _each module_, not to the entire program.

Comment: @Dyz He already _does_ call `moduleTest.test()`. (He also call `test()` after that, but presumably that's not the part he's asking about, because his code never gets that far; the correct call raises the `NameError` he's asking about.)

Comment: Ok, I can copy over main values but it does not seem to recognize tkinter Label names either. If I am to copy over every single variable I ever created, what is even the point of having a module? Seems easier for me to just duplicate my function and rename it.

Answer (score 2):

Python globals are global to *each module*, not to the whole program.

The usual way to deal with this is to not use globals.

For your toy example, you can `def test(a, b):` and then call `test(a, b)` from your main module, and that's typically the right solution, but it isn't always appropriate.

Other options are:

- Use a class, and pass the values in when you create the instance.
- Store the globals that need to be shared in a third module, which both `main` and `moduleTest` can `import thirdmodule` and access as `thirdmodule.a`. This is often appropriate for cases like shared configuration values.
- Store the globals as attributes of some other thing both pieces of code already have access to.

Answer (score 1):

As @abarnert points out, globals are global to each module. In order to solve this problem you can use:

```
def test(a, b):
    sum = a + b
    return sum
```

And

```
import moduleTest

a = 10
b = 12
print(moduleTest.test(a, b))
```

I would like to point out you should not call your variables `sum` because this already is an existing function which you're overwriting.

Comment: In that case I suggest using a class object that caries all those variables.

Comment: Yeh, I did try this solution before typing here and it did work. But my actual code has more than 2 variables. I have a function that does all of the calculations and catches out the errors which it prints in entry boxes. This function is connected to Tkinter button. Over all my GUI has 5 active Labels/Entry boxes that are linked to the function I'm trying to turn into a module. And it does not seem like you can list Tkinter variables inside the function bracket.

Comment: @user9587850 I'm not quite sure I understand, could you post that code?

Comment: I've posted code fragment below for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Here are several separate fragments of my code to give you an idea:

```
item = "SNAKE"
oldString = "-" * (len(item))
blank = "-" * (len(item))
guesses = 10

def gameOn():
    global guesses
    global oldString
    newString = ""
    i = 0
    x = len(item)
    hanged = ""
    readString = answerIn.get().upper()
    winner = 1
    if not readString:
        if guesses == 10:
            pass
        else:
            hanged = (HANGMAN[(len(HANGMAN) -1) - guesses])
            hangedOutput.config(state=NORMAL)
            hangedOutput.delete("1.0",END)
            hangedOutput.insert(END,hanged)
            hangedOutput.config(state=DISABLED)
        error.config(state=NORMAL)
        error.delete(0,END)
        error.insert(0,"Please enter the value.")
        error.config(state=DISABLED)

win = Tk()
answerIn = Entry(win,width = 3, border = 2)
answerIn.focus_set()
answerIn.grid(row=2, column=0, pady = 10, padx = 200, sticky = W)
win.mainloop()
```

When I turn it into a module it keeps asking not just for item and oldString definitions but also for answerIn, hangedOutput and etc which are part of Tkinter labels.